# Matplotlib bbox_to_anchor with subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following problem:
I am trying to plot some data on the same figure using subplots and two columns for the legends because otherwise it gets into the figure and I cant see the data.

---

You can see the code [more or less] here:

```
for i in range(no_of_cust_clusters):
    ax[i] = plt.subplot(gs[i],)
    df[i].plot(ax=ax[i])
    ax[i].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0, 0, 1, 1),
       bbox_transform=plt.gcf().transFigure,ncol=2)
```

---

I have also tried:

```
bbox_to_anchor=(0, 0, 1, i/no_of_cust_clusters)
bbox_to_anchor=(0, 0, 1, i)
```

> Also note that gs is gridspec in order to customize the location.

Though, when I am plotting the data, all of the legends go to the top right corner of the figure (as I've said I have one figure with multiple subplots, specified by gridspec). How can I solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: By specifying `bbox_transform=transFigure` and then the same `bbox_to_anchor` position, you're explicitly telling `legend` to put the legend in the same place in the figure, regardless of which axes it's on.  What are you wanting the result to look like?  Perhaps you'd prefer to have one legend with all of the artists from all subplots on it instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the end of the for loop that solved the problem!

```
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(-0.02, 1),ncol=3,bbox_transform=ax[i].transAxes)
```

-0.02 goes for "outside of the box (X)" and 1 goes for starting from the upper top (Y)

---

Thanks tom!

Answer (score 2):

Try setting your transform to the current axis to put the legends on the different subplots

```
bbox_transform=ax[i].transAxes
```